# Sending Azure token to API back-end keeps returning 401 Unauthorzied error when OnTokenValidated is added to the API

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

Recently we have created a React front-end which communicates with our API back-end following this tutorial: https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36

Just as in the tutorial we have set-up the authentication in the front-end with the adal-react library. We added/registered the front-end in azure.

Next we created our API (.Net Core 2) and also registered this in the azure environment, the config is setup in the appsettings:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantDomain": "our_azure_environment.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "our_azure_environment.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "our_front-end_azure_id_1234"
  }
```

In the API we also added the JWT middleware in the **ConfigureServices** as follow:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
             {
                 sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

             })
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                 options.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";

             });
```

When testing (calling an endpoint from the front-end) after logging in the front-end works, the data is being returned and the user is authenticated (api endpoint has the `Authorize` attribute), when not logged in the api endpoint returns 401 (as it should).

**The problem is as follows:**
When I add the following piece of code to the API **ConfigureServices** (which I want to use to do some additional stuff after authenticating) :

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                 {
                     OnTokenValidated = context =>
                     {

                         //Check if user has a oid claim
                         if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "oid"))
                         {
                             context.Fail($"The claim 'oid' is not present in the token.");
                         }
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     }
                 };
```

suddenly, the calls to the API endpoint return a **401 (Unauthorized)** error when logged in.. Though, if I remove the `OnTokenValidated` part it works fine.

When reaching the `OnTokenValidated`, the token should already be validated / authenticated or am I wrong? 
IntelliSense also says; `Invoked after the security token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.`

Did I forgot to add some setting? My feeling tells me that it is propably a wrong setup in azure itself but I have actually no clue.

The same token which is send from the front-end to the API is also being send to the graph API, when doing this, graph asks to give consent and after agreeing it works. With this in mind I believe I should add some permission to the API or something but I am not sure.

**UPDATE**

juunas pointed out in his comment below that I was using the wrong  `ClaimsPrincipal value` this fixed the initial problem but now the following gave me the 401 error:

In my **ConfigureServices** (before the `AddAuthentication` part) I have added the following to manage / add users to my AspNetUsers table (in my azure database):

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TRSContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When adding this code to the pipeline, I once more get the 401 error in the front-end. Any clue why this is?

**UPDATE2**

I found the solution for above (update). This was caused due to `AddIdentity` taken over the Authentication from JWT. This can be avoided by adding:

- `Options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`
- `Options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`

to `.AddAuthentication` options:

```
services.AddAuthentication(Options =>
             {
                 Options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 Options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
                 Options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
             })
```

More information about the above can be found here: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1376

Comment: Well, one problem might be that you are looking for a claim with type `"oid"`, but .NET ClaimsPrincipal will translate that to `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"`. Try that instead :)

Comment: @juunas Thanks a lot, this fixed the error. However, now I am getting errors with the follow up code. Perhaps you have some helpful input for that as well (posted as update in the main post).

Comment: That one I don't know why it happens :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears in the first case due to the fact that .NET `ClaimsPrincipal` objects translate the oid claim type to: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier`.

So it needs to be like:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        //Check if user has a oid claim
        if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))
        {
            context.Fail($"The claim 'oid' is not present in the token.");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```